# Why won't Joomla render my PHP/Javascript tags on the front page?

Tags: joomla

This is my first project on website development using Joomla. I am trying to make a dashboard implementation. My  problem is that whenever I edit my script in article using source tags, the changes are not reflected on my site immediately. I have even tried restarting my Wamp server, but in vain. Any tips that I should follow? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Joomla-Version there are different options to check to suppress stripping or filtering of tags like `<script>` for the frontend. Here are some hints:

First of all your tags could be filtered out client-sided depending on the editor you selected. If you use the standard TinyMCE e.g. go to Extensions - Plugins - TinyMCE where you will find a list of prohibited Elements which may include `script`. Be exactly sure what you do though, always check who should be allowed to enter script tags in an article, this is almost always a major security risk if anybody else like you as an administrator has the right to use them. So another option could be to just set the editor for your administrator/author accout to plain text and leave TinyMCE untouched.

Another filtering is done server-sided by joomla itself which can be controlled in "Global Configuration" -> "Text filter". After a standard installation all groups will use Default Black List filtering which includes removing script tags. Here you could define "No Filtering" for the Super User group e.g.

Again, all this depends on your Joomla-Version (my examples are referring to 2.5) and are hints to get around the issue but without knowing your security concept.